# How to Scrape Five Tables from This BloomBerg Site?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

From this site: https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2020-us-election-results

I want to scrape the 5 tables in the Race Competitive Ratings section (Solid Democratic, Lean Democratic, Toss-Up, Lean Republican, and Solid Republican).

I am having difficulty doing that using BeautifulSoup for some reason but it worked for some other sites I have tried with.

Here is my code:

```
web_url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2020-us-election-results'
response = requests.get(web_url)

soup_object = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

soup_object

data_table = soup_object.find_all('table')

data_table
```

The result that I get for data_table is:

```
[]
```

But I expected 5 different tables from that section to appear in my list.

Is there something I have to do to modify my code in order to get past this?

Comment: Are the tables loaded in via javascript? have you tried loading the page in your browser without javascript to see if it still shows the data. BS doesnt use javascript so any content loaded by JS to the DOM wont be seen by BS

Comment: diable javascript and re-load page.  The tables don't build.  You'll either need to use something like selenium or work out javascript being run on page and possibly run other http requests to get data